# Logging in with Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: authentication

Is it possible to log a user programmatically with Windows Identity Foundation regardless of the authentication scheme used on SharePoint (claims / forms)?

Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more; do you want to do a client authn or do you need to do it actively from an application or impersonate a user inside SharePoint?

Comment: I am trying to implement a single solution for both our internal server and SharePoint Online. SharePoint Online uses WIF so I wonder if same is possible with SharePoint Server.

Comment: Élodie, were you able to throw together a sample that programmatically logs in to SPO in an ADFS scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint (365 and on-premise) both uses WIF for claims based authn, even though 365 has implemented some non standard quirks to handle the federated logout scenarios. So if you question is if you can use WIF with SharePoint the answer is Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you think of my solution then, is it a good way to implement a uniform login system?

Comment: You should definatley take a look at ADFS if you'd like to have SSO to SP on-prem and SP online. There's no need to build a custome fed authn solution.